# Jquery Validate Plugin  to allow only text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, validation

I'm using following jquery plugin

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

my current script is

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function($) {  
$("#answer55937X1X3othertext").mask("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",{ placeholder:"#" });
});
</script>
```

**Problem:**

But actually I would like to allow user to enter text only of any number of characters. Ex: words, Phrases or even sentences. So I figured regex would be good fit.

**Question 1:**

Any idea how to implement regex in this plugin ? If not please suggest alternative.Please include regex code too.

**Question 2:**(out of curiosity)

I did look at the website but couldn't find anything related to regex. Is regex by default included in plugins ? I don't know how to check whether that feature is included or not.

Thanks in advance

**Update:**

I tried below script but it is not working.

```
    $('question'+QQ' input.text').bind('keypress', function (event) {
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
if (!regex.test(key)) {
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
}
    });
```

Comment: Why would you expect this plugin to support regular expressions?

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know, you can't do that using 'masked input', it doesn't support the requirement you want.

it would perfactly fit for those input that having "fixed length", e.g.

```
an input with 8 length: 010-55555  (phone numbers)
an input with 8 or 11 length:  086-010-55555 (another phone numbers)
```

it does not support this:

```
this is a sentence that doesn't have fixed words.
```

Since it has to first of all fullfil the input with place holder "#".

If you want to validate the input, just write your own customized functions, using Really simple validations or other jquery validation frameworks, or even your own:

```
<input id="your_field" />

<script>
$("#your_field").blur(function(){
  // your implementation here....
  $(this).val().match(...)  
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Any alternative to this situation ?

Comment: use Really Simple Validation(http://www.benjaminkeen.com/software/rsv/) or jquery validate(http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But how to implement regex in this plugin ? can you please give me an example. I'm looking at the documentation now.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use the mask plugin if you want to allow the user to enter whatever they want?

Besides, after looking at the page, it doesn't look like the plugin accepts regular expressions (please correct me if I'm wrong). For example, they use the `*` character to represent any alphanumeric character. In regular expressions, the `*` character has special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Hello fellow stackoverflower! I've just spent 20 minutes or so designing a jquery plugin that I'm hoping you, as well as many others, will be able to implement for this input masking. Please keep in mind, this is very quick work, and I hope to add to it, but just let me know if it fulfills your needs!

https://github.com/bmoyles0117/jQuery-SimpleMask

Please feel free to try to implement it using the code below, "a" stands for alphabetical, "#" stands for alphanumeric including spaces, and "9" of course stands for numbers. What I've done, is add flags to the initial config to say whether or not you'd like to allow periods, commas, or dashes. I really hope this fulfills your need!

```
<script src="jquery.simplemask.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#test123').simpleMask('aaaaa-####999', {
            allow_periods   : true,
            allow_commas    : true,
            allow_dashes    : true
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="text" id="test123" />
```

Comment: If you'd like for me to add the placeholder characters, for characters not yet fulfilled, let me know and I'll gladly do so!

Comment: Bryan thanks for the plugin. As you can see from discussion I actually don't need input mask , I need a simple validator. If you can make a validator that would be great